# ROS2, No executable found

Tags: ros, ros2, python3, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have successfully created few ROS2 nodes (one for a publisher with customer message, the custom message one, one responsible for debugging, one for the subscriber).

I have repeated the exact same steps in order to create some other packages.
However, the last one that I created returns "No executable found".

I am developing using python3.

I am pretty sure that package.xml, setup.py, setup.cfg and the actual node class are fine.

Also, no issues when running rosdep, all fine with colcon build, and I have installed everything with . install/setup.bash.

What could the problem be? Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
G.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354719/ros2,-no-executable-found/) by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on 2020-06-12**:
Do you see the executable when you run?

```
ros2 pkg executables <pkg_name>
```

**Comment by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on 2020-06-12**:
yes, I can see the package being there...

**Comment by [Uik](https://answers.ros.org/users/108823/uik/) on 2022-07-13**:
in my case, i didn't see anything with this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the error was caused by wrong action on my side..
I built and installed without realizing at the wrong level of the project tree.. that was enough to mess things up ...

lol

---

Originally posted by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) with karma: 60 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0